# Need help parsing values into HTTP Patch Request

Tags: azure, http, azure-logic-apps, http-patch

I am trying to create an Azure Logic App to activate/deactivate a user.

This is the actual user data set that I have.

End Goal: I am trying to change "active":false

```
{
      "emails": [
        {
          "type": "work",
          "value": "anna@example.com",
          "primary": true
        }
      ],
      "externalId": "111",
      "active": true,
      "groups": [
        {
          "display": "users",
          "type": "direct",
          "value": "11",
          "$ref": "Groups/11"
        }
   `   ],
      "id": "001",
      "userName": "anna@example.com"
}
```

[image]

I have used these parameters but I received this error:

```
"{
  "schemas": [
    "urn:ietf:params:api:messages:2.0:Error"
  ],
  "detail": "class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.lang.Boolean (java.lang.String and java.lang.Boolean are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')",
  "status": "500"
}"
```

Any idea what should I add/change to get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using Azure AD connector to activate/deactivate a user in logic app or which connector is being used here? Can you share your whole flow, so that it will be easier to help?

Comment: Hello I am using a custom connector to deactivate a user in Azure DataBricks. I have done the flow before and it works but I forgot the values I placed for the HTTP Patch request.

After I have done it previously, it's more of the syntax that I need help with. Like for example, operation - replace, operationspath, value and schema